# Bold text detection

Tags: computer-vision, research

I am currently working on a project where I need to detect bold text on a multi font-size image (so no mathematic morphology possible). This detection will be used in parallel of an OCR system (with tesseract) to detect which information (in bold) are important in a document.

I already tested the wordFontAttribute() function of tesseract but it is inconsistent : it provide me poor results of bold detection and decresease the performance of my OCR system because to use this function an old version of tesseract (v3) is needed.

I found a couple of scientific researchs who were based on font style detection and so on bold detection ("[Automatic Detection of Italic, Bold and All-Capital Words in Document Images](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Detection+of+Italic%2C+Bold+and+All-Capital+Words+in+Document+Images&btnG=)" and "[Script Independent Detection of Bold Words in
Multi Font-size Documents](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Script+Independent+Detection+of+Bold+Words+in+Multi+Font-size+Documents&btnG=)" on google scholar).

I was wondering if there is an code implementation of this research online.

Any others ideas on bold detection is also welcome